# How to keep popover on fixed element after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm attempting to position a button element that can have a Popover spring out of it with a form inside of it for a user to take notes in, but I seem to be having issues with the popover not showing up where it should.  Initially it seems fine, but as a user scrolls down the page and attempts to open the button the Popover appears out of position, further down the screen and off the screen the further the user scrolls down.

html:

```
<button type="button" id="showNotes"  uib-popover-template="$scope.dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-placement="right" class="btn feedback-btn btn-info pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Feedback</button>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">

    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <strong> Notes</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="40" ng-model="$scope.notes"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="$scope.saveNotes()"> Save Notes </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.feedback-btn {
    position: fixed;
    top: 275px;
    left: -31px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.dynamicPopover = { templateUrl: "myPopoverTemplate.html" };
```

Comment: possible to set up a plnkr isolating this?

Comment: I can later tonight.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix